# How to pick up header info (e.g. subject) from an email received via an HTTP Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am using [CloudMailin](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/receiving_email/examples/ruby/#rails3/) in an attempt to upload profile pics to a mobile device web site via email. Using their documentation I have...

incoming_mails_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    ...
    user_id = params[:headers][:subject] # line 13
    ...
  end
```

The error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/incoming_mails_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

The relevant portion of the log:

```
Apple-Mail=_...\r\n", "x_references"=>"sample@example.com", "x_cc_header"=>"", "subject"=>"Smith, Joe"}
```

Rummaged around the web for a solution and didn't find a solution. Thanks for your help.

---

### Update:

Placed the following in the controller:

```
::Rails.logger.info "PARAMS INSPECT: " + params.inspect
```

The following is only a very small portion of what it yielded:

```
PARAMS INSPECT: {"message"=>"Received: by ... :content-type:subject:date:message-id:to:mime-version:x-mailer\r\n...
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"Apple-Mail=_..."\r\n
Subject: Smith, John\r\n ...
"return_path"=>"yada@blah.com", 
"x_from_header"=>"[\"blay@yada.com\"]", ...
"subject"=>"Smith, John"
```

Comment: Could you link the specific page of their docs you used? If the data you need is in the params hash (as you appear to expect), I would start by outputting `params.inspect` to your log or something, just to see if you can figure out where the data is.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus, updated the link to the specific page. Will update with params.inspect as soon as i get results... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be certain of the exact structure of the params hash and any sub-hashes without the full (presumably long) print out of params, but it looks as though there's a parameter for each header, including a 'subject' parameter (`params[:subject]`, probably?). Is that what you needed?

Comment: In case it's of use to anyone else. The exact format of each of the CloudMailin message formats is at http://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/.